# android - TextView doesn't displayed in RecyclerView

Tags: android, textview, android-recyclerview

I've got an app which got some data (titles of youtube videos) and displayed them in the TextViews which in the items in RecyclerView. But some of TextViews are not displayed, but data is loaded correctly.

On my phone don't displayed only few elements of list, on my old tabled - almost all elements are not displayed.

I do some experiments and learned that **strings longer then some value are not displayed.**

#### List item

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
             android:layout_margin="1dp"
             android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
             android:orientation="vertical"
             android:padding="3dp"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/galley_photo_item_image"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="120dp"/>
        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/galley_photo_item_checkbox"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:buttonTint="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:visibility="invisible"/>
    </FrameLayout>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="WTF"
        android:minLines="3"
        android:maxLines="3"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:id="@+id/image_name_text"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

#### My Adapter

```
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int i)
{
    View convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gallery_photo_item,parent,false);
    ViewHolder view_holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
    //view_holder.Position = i;

    //Event handling
    view_holder.CheckBox.setOnClickListener(this);
    view_holder.View.setOnClickListener(this);


    convertView.setTag(view_holder);
    //checkBox.setTag(position);

    return view_holder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder view_holder, int position)
{
    //Toggle checkbox on DELETE MODE
    if(is_checking) {
        view_holder.CheckBox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        view_holder.CheckBox.setChecked(checked[position]);
    }
    else
        view_holder.CheckBox.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    //view.setTag(position);
    view_holder.CheckBox.setTag(position);
    view_holder.Position=position;

    //Display image
    //String uri = Uri.fromFile(thumbs[position]).toString();
    String uri = thumbs_fnames[position];
    Glide.with(context)
            .load(uri)
            .centerCrop()
            .into(view_holder.ImageView);

    //Добавляем подписи (если есть)
    if((thumbs_descriptions!=null))//&&(thumbs_descriptions.length==thumbs_fnames.length))
    {
        String text = thumbs_descriptions[position];
        Log.d("ImageListAdapter",position +": "+text+"|");
        view_holder.Description.setText(text);
    }
    else
        Log.d("ImageListAdapter",position + ": nothing");


    if(position== markred_id)
        view_holder.View.setBackgroundResource(R.color.colorPrimary);
    else
        view_holder.View.setBackgroundResource(R.color.transparent);

}
```

And the last strange thing. When I set the text manually:

`text = "Some long-long text bla-bla-bla ... ... ... ...;`

it works correctly.

### What the strange problem?

Comment: Can you see the text in the logs when this line is executed? Log.d("ImageListAdapter",position +": "+text+"|");

Comment: can you show your view holder and where you assign the value to the textview

Comment: Yes, I can see text in log, It's OK.

Comment: I assign value to the textView here:
`view_holder.Description.setText(text);`. ViewHolder just contains few view (TextView, ImageView) and use `findViewById` in constructor

Comment: can you paste the full code of the ViewHolder class?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/MaKyyja0 ViewHolder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did it. The problew was that `FrameLayout` has width and height `mathc_parent` instend `wrap_content`.

#### Correct XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
         android:layout_margin="1dp"
         android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
         android:orientation="vertical"
         android:padding="3dp">

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/galley_photo_item_image"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"/>
    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/galley_photo_item_checkbox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:buttonTint="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:visibility="invisible"/>
</FrameLayout>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minLines="3"
    android:maxLines="3"
    android:id="@+id/image_name_text"/>
```

### Diff: https://www.diffchecker.com/qe8pcozv

You can also see difference in TextView height, but it doesn't metter, It works in both situations.